# Flutter firebase storage CORS issue

Tags: firebase, flutter-web

I'm using a free plan of firebase storage. All working good but the image not loading on my flutter web.

I'm getting this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sap-app-8318e.appspot.com/o/cover%2Fimage_cropper_028D7F16-0161-4E90-B40D-EE47D310F322-5339-000003697F67306C.jpg?alt=media&token=313475a9-9728-4e61-97da-f5d5534bb008' from origin 'https://sap.nextcardpro.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sap-app-8318e.appspot.com/o/cover%2Fimage_cropper_028D7F16-0161-4E90-B40D-EE47D310F322-5339-000003697F67306C.jpg?alt=media&token=313475a9-9728-4e61-97da-f5d5534bb008:1
```

I searched on google everyone told need to allow CORS Access from firebase, but how can I have to add it. but how can I add it to my free firebase plan?

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Finally, solve by this post after 2 days of google search.

https://bitmovin.com/docs/encoding/faqs/how-do-i-set-up-cors-for-my-google-cloud-storage-bucket

Comment: Bravo! you saved my life. Thanks !

Comment: in my case i got does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. with email account and service account... any solution for this.

Comment: Thank you for good infomation! Arigatogozaimasu!

Comment: precise answer, thank you!

Comment: and you ended my struggles, even chatGPT couldn't help lol, after about 7 hours chatting with it

Comment: For the lazy, another answerer puts the contents of this no-longer-existing page here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67975184.

Answer (score 33):

Answer from above link:

If you already familiar with Google Cloud Services and Tools, like gcloud and/or gsutil, you can also  checkout Google's documentation about CORS.

Login to your google cloud console: https://console.cloud.google.com/home. Click on "Activate Google Cloud Shell" in the upper right corner (see picture below):

[image: Activate Google Cloud Shell]

At the bottom of your window, a shell terminal will be shown, where gcloud and gsutil are already available. Execute the command shown below. It creates a json-file which is needed to setup the cors-configuration for your bucket. This configuration will allow every domain to access your bucket using XHR-Requests in the browser: `echo '[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],"method": ["GET", "HEAD"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors-config.json`

If you want to restrict the access one or more specific domains, add their URL to the array, e.g.: `echo '[{"origin": ["https://yourdomain.com", "http://localhost:*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],"method": ["GET", "HEAD"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors-config.json`
(localhost is also added to access resources while developing, based on your needs).

Replace `YOUR_BUCKET_NAME` with your actual bucket name in the following command to update the cors-settings from your bucket `gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME`

To check if everything worked as expected, you can get the cors-settings of a bucket with the following command: `gsutil cors get gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME`

You can find the bucket ID in the Storage panel of your project's Firebase Console:

Storage Panel of the Firebase Console
It's the value starting with `gs://`.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and as always, it took me few hours to fix but the solution is as always simple and easy.

When you run this command `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit --no-sound-null-safety` app will run and everything works fine and pixel-perfect but sadly network images failed to load. When you inspect the app look into console you will see this beautiful error

[image]

(Blocked by CORS policy) : No ‘Access-Control: Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.

**What is CORS?**

CORS stands for (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing). CORS is a browser security feature that restricts Cross-origin HTTP requests that are initiated from scripts running in the browser.

Now how to fix CORS issue? And displaying images from any other domain or from Firebase Storage. The answer is very simple follow me with the steps below

1. Open the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) you will see the screen below

[image]

2. Now select your project and click on the dashboard Button.

[image]

3. Start a cloud terminal by clicking the `>_` icon button in the top navbar as you can see in the below image

[image]

4. Click on the open editor button and (wait for few seconds)

[image]

5. Now click on 3 (...) dot and create new file and named it *cors.json* like you can see in the below image

[image]

6. Copy and paste the this code

   [ { "origin": ["*"], "method": ["GET"], "maxAgeSeconds": 3600 } ]

In the code you notice i set the origin `*` which means that every website can display your images. But you can also insert the domain of your website there to restrict the access.

7. Now run the command : `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket` When you run `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket` you will get beautiful error (‘***gsutil ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket***’) it’s mean you need to login first.
8. Run this command `gcloud auth login` and login into gcloud
9. Now again run this command ***gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket***

if you want to read more about CORS: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has a problem with installing gsutil. It will not work with python 3.10 which is the most recent one. You have to install a previous one, which version number starts with 3.7

like this one:
[download python 3.7.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/)

Answer (score 1):

Official Firebase Storage answer can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration).  May be useful if the answer ever changes.  As of April 2022, it's basically the same as Feroz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this solution by issuing two of the commands from the linked solution:

```
echo '[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],"method": ["GET", "HEAD"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors-config.json
```

This created the json configuration file. Next I needed to update the configuration for the specific bucket by issuing the second command and substituting the name of my storage bucket...

```
gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
```

Once I completed these two steps I was able to access and download files.